# How to get the request's host name in .NET 6 Web API

Tags: .net, webapi, hostname

I have tried with HttpContext.Request.Host.Host, but it returns the Web API's own host name not the request URI's host name. In other words I need the client's host name.

For example if I make a request from example.example.com to my APÌ located at api.api.com, HttpContext.Request.Host.Host will return "api.api.com".

Does this have something to do with my configuration or is this intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the request headers you find two relevant properties **origin** and **referer**.

- *referer* will be the client's url on the form: https://sub.example.com/foo/bar
- *origin* will be the client's base url on the form: https://sub.example.com

To get the host of the a url (like referer or origin) simply feed the Uri constructor with the url: `Uri uri = new Uri(url)`. You will find the host as a property on the uri object: `uri.Host`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the connection information using:

```
HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.Connection
```

And specifically the IP address with this:

```
HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress
```

Connection Info documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.connectioninfo?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: This will not work for localhost. Here the remote IP is `{::1}`.